# Read the variable value of object inside loop

Tags: javascript

I have an Object and I want to read the value of the _row.title inside the loop as dynamically

So now we have 1 array dataarr which have the list of element we want to replace inside the contentXML.
and _row is object which consist the data.

```
let _row = {title : 'Sachin',description:'Testing Code'}
for(let i =0; i < dataarr.length; i++) {
    console.log(`${dataarr[i]}`.trim())
    contentXml = contentXml.replace(`{$${dataarr[i]}`,[dataarr[i]])
}
```

The dataarr obj is

```
 [ 'BEBA8EAE-BF5A-486C-A8C5-ECC9F3942E4B' ]
[ 'actionItem item=_row' ]
[ '_row.title' ]
[ '_row.description' ]
[ '_row.type' ]
[ '_row.</w:t></w:r><w:bookmarkStart w:id="0" w:name="_GoBack"/><w:bookmarkEnd w:id="0"/><w:r><w:rPr><w:color w:val="7F7F7F"/></w:rPr><w:t>due_date_format)' ]
[ '/tablerow' ]
```

Comment: What is the value of **_row.title** in your **dataarr** example?

Comment: dataarr is an array of the element I want to replace inside the contentXML

Comment: what about using eval('string.variable.access.here') ?

Comment: What is the value of `contextXml`? Also, this just seems like it will error out `.replace(`{$${dataarr[i]}`,[dataarr[i]])`